# Subgraph isomorphism on graph sequences

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms, graph-isomorphism, parameterized-complexity

I'm looking for a subgraph isomorphism algorithm that takes advantage of properties of graph sequences.

Say $\{G_i\}_{i=1}^k$  is a sequence of graphs on vertex set $\{1 ... n\}$, and two consecutive elements $G_i$ and $G_{i+1}$ differ by an edge (i.e. either $G_{i+1}$ have one edge more than $G_i$, or one edge less than $G_i$).

Let $H$ be a graph not depending on $i$.

The problem is:

> Determine whether $H$ is a subgraph of some $G_i$.

The naive algorithm, running subgraph isomorphism from scratch on every $(G_i,H)$, has time complexity $kM$, where $M$ is the time complexity of one instance of $(G_i,H)$.

**Question: Is it possible to design a deterministic algorithm faster in terms of worst-case running time? If $N(k)$ is the maximum time needed to check $k$ graphs, is it possible to achieve $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{N(k)}{k}<M$?**

Does it help if the graphs $G$ and $H$ are very sparse (say, maximum degree≤4)?

Comment: It seems $n$ denotes both the index of a graph in the sequence and the number of vertices. You may change the sequence index to $i$, thus $\{G_i\}_{i=1}^k$ and keep $n$ for the number of vertices. Unless you really want to restrict the problem to graph sequences with as many graphs as the number of vertices.

Comment: You are describing subgraph isomorphism in the turnstile graph streaming model. The *space* complexity for subgraphs $H$ of fixed size is discussed e.g. [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dakane/CountingSubgraphs.pdf).

Comment: @smapers: Seems very similar, but maybe not identical? Note that in the question here, although you are guaranteed that $G_i$ and $G_{i+1}$ only differ in one edge, there is no restriction that you only see them "in streaming order" - you get to see all the $G_i$ up front and can strategize based on that. Also, no need to approximate the *counts* in each $G_i$ (as in the paper you linked), the question is just about telling whether $H$ *exists* in *any one* of the $G_i$.

Comment: Sure, but at least it *reduces* to it.

Comment: @smapers And the problem asks for the exact answer, not approximation.

Comment: They consider a multiplicative error, so they do decide whether there is a isomorphic subgraph.

Comment: @smapers But there's a chance that the algorithm would give the wrong answer, since (1 ± ε)-approximation only guarantees a 2/3 chance of correctness.

Comment: True, but you can easily amplify the success probability close to 1